# mbrlen() fails to return if called after std::wstring declaration and std::setlocale()

Tags: c++

mbrlen() fails to return if called after std::wstring declaration and std::setlocale().

Example:

```
#include <locale>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    std::wstring TestString;
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    mbstate_t mbs;
    size_t Res = mbrlen(NULL, 0, &mbs);    //Initialize mbs
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ -I/usr/include -std=c++0x -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib test.cpp
```

Does not return, but removing the std::wstring declaration solves the problem, so this returns fine:

```
#include <locale>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    //std::wstring TestString;
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    mbstate_t mbs;
    size_t Res = mbrlen(NULL, 0, &mbs);    //Initialize mbs
    return 0;
}
```

Or alternatively removing the `setlocale()` (while retaining the declaration) also works fine.

fedora 20, g++ 4.8.3 20140624

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should zero out `mbs` before attempting to use it.

```
#include <cstring>
memset(&mbs, 0, sizeof(mbs));
```

Or initialize it (more C++-like):

```
mbstate_t mbs{};
```

Comment: fair enough - grrr example with defect: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/mbrlen/